# Error i n creating chart (Double Creation)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a chart on my sheet Monthprepare.

I am using the below code.

I have the code , behind the button with several other calling functions.

The problem is, whenever I am creating the chart, it is creating them twice.

I am left confused what would be the reason.

Could someone help to figure it out.

```
Sub chartmonthprep()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim stable As PivotTable
Dim pt, sh
If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Set stable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2)
Set pt = stable.TableRange1
Set sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=250, _
Width:=400, Top:=20, Height:=250)
sh.Select
Set cht = ActiveChart
With cht
.SetSourceData pt
.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
End With
cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Average of Red"
cht.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
cht.SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = True
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
cht.HasTitle = True
cht.ChartTitle.Text = " Result"
End Sub
```

Comment: Before you create a new chart, make sure that you have deleted the old one. Also, this problem could be happening if this sub is being called twice in your code.

Comment: @RafaelMatos -I checked it twice. The code is called only once. also, I am deleting my sheets

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
Sub chartmonthprep()
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    'the rest of your code here --v
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim stable As PivotTable


End Sub
```

It will make sure that it is only 1 chart.

Comment: @Vityanta. Then this case, let me be more clear. I have this sheet with two Pviot tables. And I am creating each chart for each pivot. I am using the different code for the chart. By check if it is one? will it affect

Comment: If you're creating for every pivot table, you need to create a `For` loop to do that, and making instances for every pivot.

Comment: @RafaelMatos how do you mean ? Can you show me an sample ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop for each Pivot Table in a sheet with this:

```
Sub PivotTable()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each pvt In sh.PivotTables
        MsgBox pvt.Name
        'do something
    Next pvt
End Sub
```